# How to register a same COM dll for different user account in the same system

Tags: c++, com

I have a win32 COM dll.  I want to register this dll for different users in the same system.

The  dll location is different for each user.

```
C:\users\user1\mydll.dll
C:\users\user2\mydll.dll
C:\users\user3\mydll.dll
```

The installation process will register dll.

**The Issue:**

if user1 uninstall the product, mydll.dll will be unregistered, so application will not run for user2 and user3.

**Solution:**

Can I register mydll.dll for each user separately.(user1, user2 etc)

Comment: I _think_ you can use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` to do this. I am not posting this as answer as I have never done it but it would be worth pursuing.

Comment: This causes more problems than it solves.  Windows Installer already knows how to reference count a deployed DLL.  Use a merge module or whatever the installer builder supports.  Like http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/aa293070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you should put your dll in shared location (ex: D&S\Application Data\My Company\Shared) and installer should mark it as "shared file" (i don't know what installer you are using, i'm using Inno Setup, and it has such option, and if i'm right this is standard in Windows). 
So, unregistration should proceed only when shared ref count is zero.

Also MS reccomendations are the same http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954376.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can't register (as a single user) a DLL for other users. If you have sufficient privileges, you can register a DLL on a given machine (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`), and you can obviously register it for yourself (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`), but you can't register it for other users (`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-*`).

You'd probably encountered the same problem before, when trying to write `C:\users\user2\mydll.dll` with the permissions of user1. While Administrator users are powerful and can write to `\Program Files\`, they're not omnipotent. User directories are off-limit.

Comment: can't *impersonate* another user?

Comment: @MSalters All users should have administrative privilege to install my software. The installer will check if the dll is already registered, if so it will unregister and regsiter the dll again (this wont work for multi user case),. can you please let me know the good solution for my requirement

Comment: @chac: No, not without credentials. @ kanden: It more and more sounds like you're trying to solve another problem. Go back one step. What problem made you think you needed all those DLLs and all those registrations? Now ask that question here on StackOverflow. You can link to this question to show what you've tried, and my answer why your first idea didn't work out.